# Unable to execute /usr/lib/sendmail -t -i

Tags: php, email

Out of the blue my VPS stopped sending emails, the only clue that I've got is Magento's log which says 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. Unable to execute /usr/lib/sendmail -t -i'

I'm able to send emails with

```
echo "Test mail from postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" email@email.com
```

works, as well as sendmail -t
If I try to send an email using a simple script with the mail() function it just returns false.

sendmail_path in php.ini was set up to `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`, I've tried changing it to `/usr/lib/sendmail -t -i` but the same error happens.

maillog is clean.
mailq is empty.

The VPS was sending emails normally two days ago, I didn't change anything on the server.
Thanks.

As @MarcGiroux suggested it could be a permission issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

If I execute `php -f mailtest.php` as a non-root user it sends the email, but if I go to mailtest.php on the browser it doesn't.

EDIT
If mailtest.php is outside of Magento's folder it actually sends the email. The code in mailtest.php is:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $from = "emailtest@domain.com";
    $to = "email@email.com";
    $subject = "Test";
    $message = "Message";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    var_dump(mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers));
?>
```

Comment: Is sendmail in `/usr/lib/sendmail` or `/usr/lib/sendmail` ? Run `which sendmail` to find out exactly where it is. Check all php.ini's for the correct path, and look within your code to see if it's set anywhere.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it might be some access right on sendmail on your folder. Validate the access right.

Comment: It's /usr/sbin/sendmail, but both work if I try sending email with them. I've changed php sendmail_path just to test.

Comment: The permissions are as follow:
/usr/sbin/sendmail
 dr-xr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x usr
 dr-xr-xr-x sbin
 lrwxrwxrwx sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta
   dr-xr-xr-x /
   drwxr-xr-x etc
   drwxr-xr-x alternatives
   lrwxrwxrwx mta -> /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
     dr-xr-xr-x /
     drwxr-xr-x usr
     dr-xr-xr-x sbin
     -rwxr-xr-x sendmail.postfix

Answer (score 0):

It was actually HHVM that was causing the problem. Not sure why though. I've had to restart it because of an unrelated reason and it fixed the email problem. Thanks for the help guys.